# How can i write loop for procedure to insert bulk record in table using sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to insert bulk records in table using plsql and i have created procedure now i want to call this procedure in loop so i can send dynamic id in each call and i can insert many records.

how to loop the procedure and send dynamic values?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the original text to your question, and possibly format with code format tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet -

```
BEGIN
     FOR I IN 1..100 LOOP
         EXEC TODOS_BULK_INSERT('G_Leg_000' || I, I, 'system');  -- You can pass only 3 params since you have only 3 params in your proc.
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks i used below code and its working